# Rails - Simple Form - Force a non-multiple select input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am creating an input form for a Post model with Simple Form on a Rails app. The Post model is associated to a Keyword model with a has_and_belongs_to_many. To fill up the Tags in the form, I am using:

```
<%= f.association :keywords, collection: Keyword.all(order: 'name'), prompt: "Select keyword..." %>
```

which creates a html `:select` tag for the input. The problem is, because is a many to many association, Simple Form assigns the `:multiple` tag to `:select` by default, allowing selecting many objects. But I do want to **force it** to output a simple `<select>` with **no multiple** for this field.

Any idea how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, pass `:input_html => { :multiple => false }`

```
<%= f.association :keywords, collection: Keyword.all(order: 'name'), prompt: "Select keyword...", :input_html => { :multiple => false } %>
```